# Command-line to reverse byte order/change endianess

Tags: java, swap, endianness, dataoutputstream

I'm hacking around in some scripts trying to parse some data written by Javas `DataOutputStream#writeLong(...)`. Since java always seems to write big endian, I have a problem feeding the bytes to `od`. This is due to the fact that `od` always assumes that the endianess matches the endianess of the arch that you are currently on, and I'm on a little endian machine.

I'm looking for an easy one-liner to reverse the byte order. Let's say that you know that the last 8 bytes of a file is a long written by the aforementioned `writeLong(...)` method. My current best attempt to print this long is

```
tail -c 8 file | tac | od -t d8
```

, but `tac` only seems to work on text (fair enough). I've found some references to `dd conv=swab`, but this only swaps bytes in pairs, and cannot reverse these eight bytes.

Does anyone know a good one-liner for this?

Comment: Please give a sample input / output and remove Java from the equation. Do you want to invert every 8 bytes, or all bytes? For all bytes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461625/bashreverse-the-order-of-characters-in-a-string Similar: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13137/in-bash-how-to-convert-8-bytes-to-an-unsigned-int-64bit-le

Comment: @CiroSantilli六四事件法轮功纳米比亚威视: Nope, won't do. Problem already solved.

Comment: The proper solution would be to use something other than `DataOutputStream`. A `DataOutputStream` uses a specific format, and that format is always big-endian. If you want something else, then you shouldn't be using `DataOutputStream`. Also, if you write anything other than longs, you will end up corrupting the data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Resorted to Perl in the end. Used a one-liner which I found at [PERL One Liners](http://www.unixguide.net/unix/perl_oneliners.shtml):

```
tail -c 8 file | perl -0777e 'print scalar reverse <>' | od -t d8
```

The `0777` separator char was a bit puzzling to me, but [this](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/298) page at debian admin seems to suggest that it is a placeholder for 'no record separator', triggering a complete reverse byte-per byte.

Other suggestions are welcome.

EDIT: Found another command in a comment to tac.c, which I downloaded from GNU coreutils:

> Copy each FILE, or the standard input if none are given or when a
>      FILE name of "-" is encountered, to the standard output with the
>      order of the records reversed.  The records are separated by
>      instances of a string, or a newline if none is given.  By default, the
>      separator string is attached to the end of the record that it
>      follows in the file.
>
> Options:
>      -b, --before         The separator is attached to the beginning
>                                   of the record that it precedes in the file.
>      -r, --regex          The separator is a regular expression.
>      -s, --separator=separator    Use SEPARATOR as the record separator.
>
> To reverse a file byte by byte, use (in bash, ksh, or sh):
>   **tac -r -s '.\|
>   ' file**

Answer (score 13):

You could use objcopy:

```
$ objcopy -I binary -O binary --reverse-bytes=num inputfile.bin outputfile.bin
```

where num is either 2 or 4.

Comment: This has the advantage of working on Windows as well.

Answer (score 11):

Used dd, Luke!

```
dd if=sourcefile of=resultfile conv=swab
```

Comment: This do the job for short (16bits) not long (64bits), isn't it ?

Comment: Yes.  Sorry I missed topic start.

Comment: I wish I could upvote you 25 times. This is so smart and awesome and exactly solves what I needed, and I had no idea that dd option existed. And I'm on Mac so od can't do endian specification. Perfect.

Comment: Note that this only works for pairs of bytes and not for, say, 32-bit words.

Answer (score 3):

Note the next version of GNU coreutils (>= 8.23) will add the --endian={little,big} option to the od command

Comment: Due to this question?

Answer (score 2):

I came up with this Perl one-liner to convert 4-byte integers from one endianness to another:

```
$ perl -e 'open F,shift; do { read(F,$a,4); print scalar reverse($a);} while(!eof(F));' bigend.bin > littlend.bin
```

That probably works fine on real Linux machines, but Cygwin bit me in the end, treating the binary file as text and inserting a 0x0D (aka CR) before each 0x0A byte (aka newline). But if you pipe to `cat -`, it seems to leave it alone. This works for me:

```
$ perl -e 'open F,shift; do { read(F,$a,4); print scalar reverse($a);} while(!eof(F));' bigend.bin | cat - > littlend.bin
```

Comment: Best solution I've found on macOS. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

BASH:

```
od -b -v -w8 | while read pfx b8 ; do [ "$b8" ] && echo -n 12345678 | tr 87654321 \\${b8// /\\} ; done
```

To be a bit more robust depending on the output style of `od`, it may need to compress spaces ( insert `"| sed 's/  */ /g'"` after the `w8`).

Answer (score 1):

`xxd` has two flags `-e` and `-g` for your purpose.

```
    -e          little-endian dump (incompatible with -ps,-i,-r).
    -g          number of octets per group in normal output. Default 2 (-e: 4).
```

This way, you can do:

```
tail -c 8 file | xxd -e -g8
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple Python approach that reverses every 4 bytes.  Uses newer Python 3.8+ walrus operator:

```
import sys
while word := sys.stdin.buffer.read(4):
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(bytes(reversed(word)))
```

The above is simple to understand, but if you want a more compact oneliner, you can modify the above script into:

```
python3 -c $'import sys\nwhile word := sys.stdin.buffer.read(4):\n sys.stdout.buffer.write(bytes(reversed(word)))'
```

Note the `$''` notation assumes you're using bash.  It allows you to use newlines in the Python command.

As an example, swapping some chars on stdin:

```
# echo ABCDEFGH | python3 -c $'import sys\nwhile word := sys.stdin.buffer.read(4):\n sys.stdout.buffer.write(bytes(reversed(word)))'
DCBAHGFE
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that this command worked well for swapping 4 bytes for endianness

```
xxd -e input.bin | xxd -r > output_bs.bin
```