# reverse the order of characters in a string

Tags: bash

In string "12345", out string "54321". Preferably without third party tools and regex.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121162/how-to-reverse-a-string-made-of-digit-in-bash

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Simple:

```
var="12345"
copy=${var}

len=${#copy}
for((i=$len-1;i>=0;i--)); do rev="$rev${copy:$i:1}"; done

echo "var: $var, rev: $rev"
```

Output:

```
$ bash rev
var: 12345, rev: 54321
```

Comment: +1 This can be easily extended to reverse `ascii hex` bytes for instance.

Comment: I added an [improved answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34668251/2350426) as my edit was not accepted (included a POSIX solution).

Answer (score 212):

I know you said "without third-party tools", but sometimes a tool is just too obviously the right one, plus it's installed on most Linux systems by default:

```
[madhatta@risby tmp]$ echo 12345 | rev
54321
```

See [`rev`'s man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rev.1.html) for more.

Comment: But not with embedded distros such as OpenWRT :-/

Comment: Or `rev <<< 12345` in bash, zsh and ksh. (Not dash nor csh.)

Comment: I hear you, but try `echo '\xff' |rev`.  I never said that `echo -e` would work, so it seems a bit harsh to rake me over the coals when it doesn't.

Comment: This doesn't work if the string contains a newline; `rev` acts on each line independently, and doesn't appear to have any command-line options that modify this. Furthermore, as @Equidamoid's example shows (which, by the way, has nothing to do with `echo -e`), it assumes that the string is a properly encoded sequence of *characters*. If you need to reverse something by *bytes* (e.g., if you're not dealing with binary data instead of actual text), this solution doesn't work. *[Note: to fix formatting, I deleted this comment and reposted it. Apologies for possible phantom notifications.]*

Answer (score 15):

Presume that a variable 'var' has the value '123'

```
var="123"
```

Reverse the string and store in a new variable 'rav':

```
rav=$(echo $var | rev)
```

You'll see the 'rav' has the value of '321' using echo.

```
echo $rav
```

Answer (score 13):

`rev | tail -r` (BSD) or `rev | tac` (GNU) also reverse lines:

```
$ rev <<< $'12\n34' | tail -r
43
21
$ rev <<< $'12\n34' | gtac
43
21
```

If LC_CTYPE is C, rev reverses the bytes of multibyte characters:

```
$ LC_CTYPE=C rev <<< あの
��め�
$ export LC_ALL=C; LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 rev <<< あの
のあ
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning `tac`. Note that `tac` has support for passing a different delimiter than `\n` using the `-s` option.

Answer (score 9):

A bash solution improving over @osdyng answer (my edit was not accepted):

```
var="12345"     rev=""

for(( i=0 ; i<${#var} ; i++ )); do rev="${var:i:1}$rev"; done

echo "var: $var, rev: $rev"
```

Or an even simpler (bash) loop:

```
var=$1   len="${#var}"   i=0   rev=""

while (( i<len )); do rev="${var:i++:1}$rev"; done

echo "var: $var, rev: $rev"
```

A POSIX solution:

```
var="12345"     rev=""    i=1

while  [ "$i" -le "${#var}" ]
do     rev="$(echo "$var" | awk -v i="$i" '{print(substr($0,i,1))}')$rev"
       : $(( i+=1 ))
done

echo "var: $var, rev: $rev"
```

Note: This works on multi byte strings. Cut solutions will work only in ASCII (1 byte) strings.

Comment: If you're going to depend on awk anyway, why not just run it once rather than in a loop? `awk '{for(i=length($0);i;i--)printf "%s",substr($0,i,1); print ""}'` or even `awk '{for(i=length($0);i;i--)x=x substr($0,i,1); print x}'`

Comment: doesn't work with globbing e.g.  var=" a * b"

Answer (score 8):

Some simple methods of reversing a string

```
echo '!!!esreveR si sihT' | grep -o . | tac | tr -d '\n' ; echo

echo '!!!esreveR si sihT' | fold -w 1 | tac | tr -d '\n' ; echo
```

Convert to hex values then reverse

```
echo '!!!esreveR si sihT' | xxd -p | grep -o .. | tac | xxd -r -p ; echo

echo '!!!esreveR si sihT' | xxd -p | fold -w 2 | tac | xxd -r -p ; echo
```

Answer (score 7):

For those without **rev** (recommended), there is the following simple **awk** solution that splits fields on the null string (every character is a separate field) and prints in reverse:

```
awk -F '' '{ for(i=NF; i; i--) printf("%c", $i); print "" }'
```

The above **awk** code is POSIX compliant. As a compliant **awk** implementation is guaranteed to be on every POSIX compliant OS, the solution should thus not be thought of as "3rd-party."  This code will likely be more concise and understandable than a pure POSIX **sh** (or **bash**) solution.

(; I do not know if you consider the null string to -F a regex... ;)

Answer (score 6):

This reverses the string "in place":

```
a=12345
len=${#a}
for ((i=1;i<len;i++)); do a=$a${a: -i*2:1}; done; a=${a:len-1}
echo $a
```

or the third line could be:

```
for ((i=0;i<len;i++)); do a=${a:i*2:1}$a; done; a=${a:0:len}
```

or

```
for ((i=1;i<len;i++)); do a=${a:0:len-i-1}${a: -i:i+1}${a:len-i-1:1}; done
```

Answer (score 5):

If `var=12345`:

[bash](/questions/tagged/bash) `for((i=0;i<${#var};i++)); do rev="$rev${var:~i:1}"; done`

[sh](/questions/tagged/sh) `c=$var; while [ "$c" ]; do rev=$rev${c#"${c%?}"}; c=${c%?}; done`

```
echo "var: $var, rev: $rev"
```

Run it:

```
$ rev
var: 12345, rev: 54321
```

Answer (score 3):

This can of course be shortened, but it should be simple to understand: the final `print` adds the newline.

```
echo 12345 | awk '{for (i = length($0); i > 0; i--) {printf("%s", substr($0, i, 1));} print "";}'
```

Answer (score 3):

Nobody appears to have posted a `sed` solution, so here's one that works in non-GNU sed (so I wouldn't consider it "3rd party"). It does capture single characters using the regex `.`, but that's the only regex.

In two stages:

```
$ echo 123456 | sed $'s/./&\\\n/g' | sed -ne $'x;H;${x;s/\\n//g;p;}'
654321
```

This uses bash format substitution to include newlines in the scripts (since the question is tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)). It works by first separating the input string into one line per character, and then by inserting each character into the beginning of the hold buffer.

- `x` swaps the hold space and the pattern space, and
- `H` H appends the (current) pattern space to the hold space.

So for every character, we place that character into the hold space, then append the old hold space to it, thus reversing the input. The final command removes the newlines in order to reconstruct the original string.

This should work for any single string, but it will concatenate multi-line input into a single output string.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another simpler `awk` solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=""} {for (i=NF; i>0; i--) s=s $i; print s}' <<< '123456'
```

```
654321
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Perl:

```
echo 12345 | perl -nle 'print scalar reverse $_'
```

Source: [Perl one-liners](https://gist.github.com/joyrexus/7328094)

Answer (score -1):

read word

```
reve=`echo "$word" | awk '{for(i=length($0); i>0;i--) printf (substr($0,i,1));}'`
echo  "$reve"
```