# Unix shell scripting to reverse a string without rev

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to write a shell script that accepts a string as a command line argument and prints out what is entered in the reverse order with out using the rev command but rather reversing the letters one by one. how would I do that?
so like 
if Flower is entered it will print out rewolF

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461625/bashreverse-the-order-of-characters-in-a-string

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 5):

A good subject for [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) *parameter expansion* :

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i=${#1}; i>=0; i--)); do printf "${1:$i:1}"; done; echo
```

Example :

```
./script.sh foobar
```

Output :

```
raboof
```

Comment: Just add the shebang and change `foobar` to `$1` and the googlephobic will be happy.

Answer (score 0):

```
s1='Flower'
a1=($(echo $s1|fold -w1 ))
for (( i=${#a1[@]}-1;i>=0;i--));do echo "$i=>${a1[i]}"; done
5=>r
4=>e
3=>w
2=>o
1=>l
0=>F
```

Comment: What about `printf '%s'  $(echo flower | fold -w1 | tac) $'\n'` ?

Comment: looks ok , except echo Flower :-)