# Reverse text file in Bash

Tags: bash, shell

How can I reverse a text file in Bash?

For example, if `some.txt` contains this:

```
book
pencil
ruler
```

then how can I get this? :

```
relur
licnep
koob
```

Comment: Just use [`tac`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tac-invocation.html). :-)

Comment: This is very similar, and does depend on a 3rd party but as the post says, on linux/mac it's usually installed anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461625/bashreverse-the-order-of-characters-in-a-string

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try the combined form of `tac` and `rev` commands,

```
$ tac file | rev
relur
licnep
koob
```

From `man tac`

> tac - concatenate and print files in reverse

From `man rev`

> The rev utility copies the specified files to standard output, reversing
>        the order of characters in every line.  If no files are specified, stan‐
>        dard input is read.

Comment: +1; OSX users: `tac` is not available there, use `tail -r` instead.

Comment: Under OsX, try this for replacing `tac`: `sed -n -e '1!G' -e '$p' -e h` or simplier: `sed -ne '1!G;$p;h'`

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS X uses FreeBSD `sed` that allows escaped newlines in its replacement string.

The following version of the solution given by F. Hauri works for `GNU sed 4.2.1`, FreeBSD `sed` and [minised 1.15](http://www.exactcode.de/site/open_source/minised/).

```
escnl='\
'

sed -ne '
    /../!b;
    s/^.*$/'"${escnl}"'&'"${escnl}"'/;
    tx;
  :x;
    s/\(\n.\)\(.*\)\(.\n\)/\3\2\1/;
    tx;
    s/\n//g;
  :;
    1!G;
    $p;
    h
' <<<$'book\npencil\nruler'
```